# Multiple rows to columns (pivot)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a table like below,

```
ClassId     ClassStDate             Gender Rate1       Rate2       Rate3       Rate4
1           2014-08-01          M      30          40          50          60
1           2014-08-01          F      26          36          46          56
```

I want my query to output like below (multiple columns instead of multiple rows)

```
classid     ClassStDate     Rate1_M     Rate1_F     Rate2_M     Rate2_F     Rate3_M     Rate3_F     Rate4_M     Rate4_F
1           2014-08-01      30          26          40          36          50          46          60          56
```

I can achieve the desired result with multiple pivots in a multiple CTEs and joining them together. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efef0/2

Is there anyway to achieve this with a single pivot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    ClassId,
    ClassStDate,
    RateNum+'_'+Gender AS RateNumGender,
    Rate
  FROM classes
  UNPIVOT(Rate FOR RateNum IN (Rate1,Rate2,Rate3,Rate4)) p
)
SELECT *
FROM t
PIVOT(SUM(Rate) FOR RateNumGender IN (Rate1_M,Rate1_F,Rate2_M,Rate2_F,Rate3_M,Rate3_F,Rate4_M,Rate4_F) )p
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efef0/22)

Comment: Nice use of unpivot to "normalize" the rate columns before pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from doing an old school MAX/CASE

```
SELECT 

   classid     ,
   ClassStDate,
   MAX(case Gender when  'M' THEN Rate1  ELSE NULL END) Rate1_M  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'F' THEN Rate1  ELSE NULL END) Rate1_F  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'M' THEN Rate2  ELSE NULL END) Rate2_M  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'F' THEN Rate2  ELSE NULL END) Rate2_F  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'M' THEN Rate3  ELSE NULL END) Rate3_M  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'F' THEN Rate3  ELSE NULL END) Rate3_F  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'M' THEN Rate4  ELSE NULL END) Rate4_M  ,
   MAX(case Gender when  'F' THEN Rate4  ELSE NULL END) Rate4_F  

FROM 

   classes
GROUP BY   
   classid     ,
   ClassStDate
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efef0/21)

Comment: I think it just boils down to personal preference at this point. Using the Case or Pivot really won't effect the performance in this example.